# How to debug EXC_BAD_ACCESS error using Profile in Xcode

Tags: xcode, debugging, exc-bad-access, profile

After I received a exc_bad_access error I read this tutorial: http://www.ioslearner.com/debugging-exc_bad_access-error-xcode-instruments/ and followed the steps:

- Run Profile
- Choose Zombies

Everything looks the same on my computer except that I do not get the Zomie Signal.

In order to make sure I did not forget a step I tried it with the example code provided in the Tutorial. There I see the Zombi Signal

**So how do I get the zombie signal in my project using Xcode -> Profile?**

This is the sample code I use:

I am well aware that the two releases cause the error. Again the question is how get the "Zombie Message" in the Profile using Xcode:

```
NSArray *currentRestaurant = [restaurants objectAtIndex:i];
RestauInfo *restauInfo = [NSEntityDescription
                         insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"RestauInfo" 
                         inManagedObjectContext:context];
[restauInfo release];
restauInfo.Name = [currentRestaurant objectAtIndex:0];
restauInfo.Cuisine = [currentRestaurant objectAtIndex:1];
NSError *error;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
[restauInfo release];// - this release would cause an EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

Another question is: Why do I get bad_access at the second release - and not when accessing restauInfo after the first release?

Comment: Could you post the error report concerning your crash? It usually offers a backtrace of your application so you can track down exactly where it went wrong!

Comment: How do I get the error report? If you mean the stack trace on the left side then: I do see some of my classes since I call release two times. But the questions is how do i get the "Zombie Message" using Profile

Comment: Run it without the debugger, thus without xcode even. It will say 'this app stopped unexpectedly', click on details and there it is.

Answer (score 1):

I found another way detecting faults in memory management:

In Xcode you can choose "Run", "Test", "Profile" and "Analyze"
(By pressing and holding the run Button in the upper left corner)

Running the analyze reveals memory management errors - such as

- over releasing
- leaks

Answer (score 0):

You are overreleasing restauInfo, its an autoreleased object and you call `-release` manually twice, causing your crashes.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/NSEntityDescription.html

Comment: I know - but how do I see that in Xcode->Profile ??? This is just an example: since there is an error I should get a Zombi Message right?

Comment: Of course I fixed it already - but I want to know how to debug exc_bad_access in the future when the case is difficult e.g. when a release var is garbage collected - then I don't have any stack tracke to fix this.

Comment: you always have a stack trace because its exc_bad_access, that signal always terminates your process